# How to read future date in c# from excel file?

Tags: c#, excel, date, datagridview

```
   string filePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
        string header = rbHeaderYes.Checked ? "YES" : "NO";
        string conStr, sheetName;

        conStr = string.Empty;
        switch (extension)
        {

            case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                conStr = string.Format(Excel03ConString, filePath, header);
                break;

            case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
                conStr = string.Format(Excel07ConString, filePath, header);
                break;
        }

        //Get the name of the First Sheet.
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                DataTable dtExcelSchema = 
   con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

                con.Close();
            }
        }

        //Read Data from the First Sheet.
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                  cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + sheetName + "]";

                   // cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * From ";

                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    oda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    oda.Fill(dt);


                    //Populate DataGridView.

                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

this is my excel file..
      [image]

and what i got is 
[image]

while reading / fetching excel sheet,
the problem is not reading future date which have 31 days in that year. like showing on the output.

I have spend my whole day for this. and i got blank. dont know what problem is going on?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: April does not have 31 days...what did you expect to see in that case?

Comment: no. actually, that date format is for Nepal.

Comment: That's a relevant information for the question. You should edit it and tell that

Comment: do you have any solution for that type of problem? for any UTC date??

Comment: I don't know what data format is used in nepal. But I must assume it is `MM/DD/YYYY`? Did you tried setting `CurrentUICulture` to Nepal?

Comment: can you suggest me, where should i put that code ?

Comment: First please answer. What does `04/31/2022` means?

Comment: 04/31/2022 - > MM/dd/YYYY

Comment: So, as i told you in my first comment, that is not a valid date. April does not have 31 days

Comment: current Nepali date is 02/03/2074!

Comment: for date validity in Nepali format it uses in Bikram Sambat (B.S.), as all people don't know standard date format (A.D).

Comment: @Pikoh: OP explained that is the date format in Nepal - the calendar used is Bikram Sambat which can have up to 32 days in a month & the number of days per month may vary from year to year. 04/31/2022 is perfectly valid in that calendar as is 08/32/2053. http://calendars.wikia.com/wiki/Bikram_Samwat

Comment: Now I understand. I'm afraid you'll need to convert the dates to occidental format or maybe set that column to be a string instead of a date

Comment: Those dates have to be converted to actual dates (the rest of the world uses) to be able to program with. The date system you're talking about is a whole different concept

Comment: @PaulF yes, I did understand (althouth it was tough).  :)

Comment: if I convert date column to general in excel it shows some random numbers

Comment: I don't mean in the excel, but in the datagrid you use to show the dates. Try setting that DataGridViewColumn to string

Comment: can i convert that numbers into the actual date while showing in datagridview then ??

Comment: Well..if those "numbers" in excel are seconds from a defined date yes,you could translate that into a valid date i guess

Comment: @pnuts I'm not a big expert in Excel :). Anyway, if that numbers express days from a defined date, that could be easily translated to a Date

Comment: @pnuts yes of course. I was understanding that maybe Excel was already doing that translation from Vikram Samvat date to days from 1/1/1900,so getting that number and translate it to a Gregorian date should be trivial. I must be wrong it seems... ;)

Answer (score 1):

.Net does not have an implementation for the nepali calendar as you can see in the docs for [System.Globalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization(v=vs.110).aspx).

But there is a nuget package that seems to work well. https://www.nuget.org/packages/NepaliDateConverter/

Implementation details can be found on the github page
https://github.com/janaks09/NepaliDateConverter

After installing this package you can convert from english to nepali and vice versa.

Example from the github page:

```
var convertedRawNepaliDate = new DateConverter().EngToNep(1993, 9, 30);

//English To Nepali date
//Separete properties for Year Month and Day.
var convertedNepaliDate = DateTime.Parse(convertedRawNepaliDate.ConvertedDate.Year.ToString() + "-" + convertedRawNepaliDate.ConvertedDate.Month.ToString() + "-" + convertedRawNepaliDate.ConvertedDate.Day.ToString());

var eqNepaliDay = convertedRawNepaliDate.ConvertedDayOfWeek; //Gives Nepali Day

//Nepali to english
var convertedRawEnglishDate = new DateConverter().NepToEng(2050, 06, 14);

var convertedNepaliDate = DateTime.Parse(convertedRawEnglishDate.ConvertedDate.Year.ToString() + "-" + convertedRawEnglishDate.ConvertedDate.Month.ToString() + "-" + convertedRawEnglishDate.ConvertedDate.Day.ToString());

var eqEnglishDay = convertedRawEnglishDate.ConvertedDayOfWeek; //Gives English Day
```